# Rising event from the same input type=hidden class"myclass" and get different values

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html.

```
<input class="gallery-next1" type="hidden" value="2"><a href="#" class="gallery-next" >unu</a></input>
```

and the following jquery

```
$(".gallery-next").click(function (){
     alert($(this).closest("input").val());
});
```

This query is showing in alert "Undefined". Do you have any ideas why i don`t get value 2 ?

Ok now 1 is everywhere how can i bind this class to the same function and get the object rising the event?

```
<input class="gallery-next1" type="hidden" value="1"><a href="#" class="gallery-next" >unu</a>
<input class="gallery-next1" type="hidden" value="2"/><a href="#" class="gallery-next" >doi</a>
<input class="gallery-next1" type="hidden" value="3"/><a href="#" class="gallery-next" >trei</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your markup is invalid.

`<input>` element doesn't have a closing tag, so your browser tries to fix the error simply setting `<a>` element after `<input>`.

Fix the markup and use either [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) or [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
$(".gallery-next").click(function() {
    alert($(this).siblings("input").val());  // or $(this).prev().val();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/cqwKw/

Comment: Ok now 1 is everywhere how can i bind this class to the same function and get the object rising the event?

Comment: GREAT IT WOrks WITH .prev();